# Unable to determine reference for profile id in views.py

Tags: python, django, primary-key

Dumb question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I use Djangos User model, with a custome Profile model (OneToOne relation).

Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    goal = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
   if created:
      Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save().
```

I have this code in my view (i want to update data inside the Profile model)

```
def home(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=id)
    form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save

    return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

My question is that what is my primary key in this situation?

## Update:

Latest home view code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from users import models
from users.models import Profile
from .forms import WeightForm
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    form = WeightForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
       profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__id=request.user.id)
       form = WeightForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save

return render(request, 'Landing/index.html',{'form':form})
```

urls (for Landing):

```
from django.urls import path
from Landing import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.home, name='landing-home'),
]
```

Comment: Please add urls.py code for home url to this question.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You won’t be able to get user profile ID from request unless it’s passed in explicitly as an argument.

## Solution

The correct way to query for profile is to do:

```
get_object_or_404(Profile, user__id=request.user.id)
```

## Note

If possible, recommend creating a custom User rather than a user profile–there hasn’t been a need for user models since Django version ~1.4.

## References

Request Object (user attribute): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Custom User model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Well, i tried it but I get this error: no such column: users_profile.id

Comment: @DánielMozsár I think there’s something wrong with your table then. id column should always exist. Ensure your migrations have been applied. Are you able to create a profile in the REPL?

Comment: Well, if I create an account it automatically creates the profile for it.

Comment: I might have figured it out. My code checks for an id when the page loads, but my userd doesn't have to be logged in to acces the page. I think if i wrap the code within an if block that might solve it

Comment: @DánielMozsár does this have to do with the lack of indentation in your home view?please share your code (latest) in your question under a separate update section. It’s likely something simple. I can only help if you share the relevant code as it is in your repo.

Answer (score 0):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_profile')

get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=request.user.user_profile.pk)
```

Comment: If I add that related name than my register/login will get screwed up

Comment: how login register/login get screwed up?

Comment: in request are you getting request.user.user_profile

Comment: I can't check it, because in order to use that form I need to be logged in. But with the related name attribute added my login system stops working "'User' object has no attribute 'profile'"

Comment: It means User model have not profile column. You are using user.pofile somewhere in your code